# How do I create the playing field for my game?

Tags: opengl, models, blender

I want to create a game with playfield as shown in the video in OpenGL

[www.youtube.com/user/stanfordcs248](http://www.youtube.com/user/stanfordcs248)

I have fair knowledge of OpenGL and I know this playfield can be rendered using several different cubes but that takes a lot of effort. Also it takes away the power of easily modifying the field. One idea that was suggested to me to solve this problem was to use an XML file describing almost every component of the game. Like the floor, walls , moving floors, moving obstacles etc. That way i can easily change the playfield when I want. But this approach also seems tedious. Also I couldn't figure out the structure of the XML that would make my life quite easy. So is there any better way to create or store information about the playfield than suggested above?

Note : Blender is also an option. But please provide a tutorial if you are suggesting the Blender way.

Comment: Do you already have an engine you're using?  Is the question about the act of making the model or rendering it to screen?

Comment: Its just the question of making and then rendering it on the scene. As you would know if you create a model in .obj format you can easily render it in opengl but .blend format is pretty hard to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to learn how to use shaders. The models are not complex, and it uses a simple bloom shader. See [This tutorial here](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) for modern OpenGL programming.

Answer (score 1):

What you are really asking is how to build an entire game with this mechanic.
Although this isn't really a full tutorial here is something to get you started..

1. Learn a programming language that OpenGL supports, I recomend C++ as it is excellent for game programming.
2. Learn basics of OpenGL; Setting up a scene, rendering textured models, displaying 2D sprites, displaying font, using shaders, and basic animation.
3. Learn a bit about game loops and game logic to make the base of your engine.
4. Study the mechanics of the game design and what you want to do with that.
5. Then try to bring them all together part to part in small increments and you will have a start to a game.

Comment: Please correct me if I am giving you a tutorial on what you already know, you left a bit of an unclear question.

Comment: I know all the basics of OpenGL. I lack knowledge in game loops and game logic. SO what I am really asking is that how should I maintain information about Levels in my game where Levels indicate the way playfield is created.

Comment: "3D Game Engine Programming" by Stefan Zerbst is a fantastic start and the structure of Quake is perfect for beginners. http://fabiensanglard.net/quakeSource/index.php